# How to filter the array in angularJS based on subarray length

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a model like this

```
   public class City
   {
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public List<Classified> Classifieds {get; set;}
     public List<Area> Areas {get; set;}
   }
```

In my angualrJs controller, I've like below

```
$scope.cities = data; // I'm getting data (array of city).
```

Now, I'm trying filter `cities` based on `Classifieds(.length > 0)` and `Areas (.length > 0)` like below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="city in cities | filter: { classifieds: '!!' }">    -- Not Working.

<tr ng-repeat="city in cities | filter: { areas: '!!' }">    -- Not Working.
```

I want some thing like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="city in cities | filter: { areas.length >0 }">    -- Tried this one as well. Not Working.
```

Comment: Can you show the content of the data array ?

Comment: It is in Json format. from webapi i'm returning List<City>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your `$scope.cities` variable contains data in the following format:

```
$scope.cities = [{name: 'a', classifieds: [], areas: []}, 
                 {name: 'b', classifieds: [], areas: [1]}, 
                 {name:'c', classifieds:[1], areas:[]}];
```

You could create a custom filter function such as:

```
$scope.hasData = function(city) {
    return city.areas.length > 0 || city.classifieds.length > 0;
};
```

usage:

```
  <td ng-repeat="city in cities | filter: hasData">{{city.name}}</td>
```

EDIT:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9sxeawr5/

Comment: Simple one. Looking for same. I'm new to angularJs. Thanks.